# Extract HTML Tables and convert into CSV file

Tags: gratis, windows-7, html, csv, table

I am looking for a free tool that can convert HTML tables into CSV files.
It should be able to do this with all HTML files of a given local directory or by a set of URLs.

- It should run on Windows 7.
- Free (open or closed source).
- Console program or GUI. It should be easy to use.
- Should be usuable without any additional programming.
- It should ignore everything and only look for tables.

Comment: Not a batch solution, but at least it will speed up the manual process (if it's a one time thing): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-to-csv/ You could have a batch script open the files in your browser one by one, but you'd still need several clicks per file.

Comment: Is the HTML well formed? HTML 5 or 4?

Comment: I do not know if it was well formed. But at least the table code was. I ended up writing a small C# console application working with LINQ and the HTML Agility Package. The main issue with the export to csv was that it did not trim the white spaces.